# How to make QGIS label only the shapes that are showing up?

Tags: qgis, labeling, rule-based

I have a layer where shapes are defined by rules (country) and secondly by categories (a type). I then select (check box) the country to show the shapes only for that country.  This works very well, as I change them on each composer and display data relevant to that country.
The problem is with the labels: they show up for all countries all the time and I cannot hide them.

Does anyone know how to make QGIS label only the shapes that are showing up?

[image]

Comment: Tested on 2.8.3: same problem.

Answer (score 3):

What version of QGIS are you using?

I'm using 2.8 and I can style a layer by 'name' and also label it, and then turn off one of the features in the layer with a checkbox in the legend, and it isn't labelled any more.

[image: Brighton added and labelled.]

[image: Brighton removed and not labelled.]

Comment: Thanks much Alex. I am using QGIS 2.10.1.  I have rule-based classification and then under it, I have made a category (see the image I just added).  If I have only one level, then it work as it works for you, but with two levels it shows the labels always... is that a bug?

Comment: Hi @jfarjona, sounds like a bug. Probably best reporting it here with a simple to reproduce case: https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 2.8 and 2.10 (maybe in earlier versions as well, can't check right now) there is an option in the Label-Settings to define which feature will be labeled. You can enter these settings as shown in the screenshot below. There you can build a query adjusting to your needs.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this could be a way.  Do you know in which variable is recorded if the current polygon is being shown?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a variable for that. Maybe you can build a query using country and type like you aldready do for the classification. Then you would have to enter some values, e.g. "country"='Argentina' to adjust the labels to your current display, but this seems like a very un-elegant way to do this :/ has anyone else some ideas?